# Swift: Reseting multiple subclassed custom uitableviewcells at the same time?

Tags: swift, uitableview, reset, custom-cell

I have 3 custom cells that are subclassed from the viewController Uitableview they are in. The cells have gesture recogniser to see where they are touched to change the icons/ backgrounds then the result is save to core data. 
I want to have the situation that the data is saved and the cells reset to base colours and graphics when any cell isn't touched for say 3 seconds (to remove a save button). I have that all done ok but I cannot make any method to reset them all at the exact same time. I have tried so many different ways and I thought the best way would be to reload the table in the viewcontroller but I couldn't make it work.
At the moment I am using a Struct with a bool touched. When the touch ends on any cell it calls a timer and if it ends without another touch it calls a method to save and reset. 
Maybe this is the wrong way to do it so Im a bit stuck.

[image: storyboard]

View controller class

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) ->     
Int {
return measurements.count

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

if indexPath.row == 0 {

   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("BmCustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! BmTableViewCell


  return cell

} else if indexPath.row == 1 {


  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("StressCustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)as! StressTableViewCell


  return cell
} else {


  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PainCustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PainTableViewCell

  return cell
      }
}
```

Sample of painTableViewCell class (same as other two)

```
// if touched the text changes and the icon changes. if not touched for 5 seconds resets to not touched.

func resetTouchedPainAfterFiveSecs (){

if TouchNotification.isBeingTouched == false {
  timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2.0, target: self, selector: Selector("reset"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
} else {
  timer.invalidate()
}
}

func reset(){

ResetTables().resetAllTables()
savePainData()
}


// reset pain ui to ready to go state
func resetPain () {
TouchNotification.reset = true

if TouchNotification.reset == true {
  painLabel.textColor = whiteColour
  painIcon.image = UIImage(named: "IconPain 0 Unused")
  touchedPain = false
  painLabel.text = "Pain"
  TouchNotification.reset = false

}
}
```

TouchNotification

```
struct TouchNotification {
static var isBeingTouched = false
static var reset = false
}
```

Reset class

```
class ResetTables: UIViewController {

func resetAllTables(){

StressTableViewCell().resetStress()
BmTableViewCell().resetBM()
PainTableViewCell().resetPain()

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say "I thought the best way would be to reload the table in the view controller but I couldn't make it work". Yep, that's precisely what I'd suggest you do (though I might suggest `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` instead).

A far more subtle issue is that, especially as your UI gets more complex,  cells can scroll off screen, can be reused, etc. As a result, you generally want to avoid updating cells directly. What if one or more of these cells have scrolled off screen by the time they need to be reset? How, when it scrolls back into view, will you know what to do with that cell? Etc.

Because of this, you often want to decouple the UI (the cells) from the model (the information about which cells are what color). Once you do that, you can move to a world that you have some model structure (in my example below, `cellBackgroundColors`) which keeps track of what color a cell should be. The `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will then set the color of the cell on the basis of this model object. Then, whenever you want to change a cell's color, you (a) update this model object and then (b) tell the table view reload that cell.

If you want to update multiple cells at the same time, you then update your model and call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` with an array of cells, and then they'll all be updated at the same time. But you'll also be doing this in a safe manner, which isn't reliant on the cells being on screen at the time. And, if I infer correctly that you want the timer to restart if they tap on something else, you can `invalidate` the timer and create a new one every time the user taps on a cell.

Here is a little example:

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    var cellBackgroundColors: [UIColor]!
    let defaultColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        resetCellBackgroundColorsToDefault()
    }

    func resetCellBackgroundColorsToDefault() {
        cellBackgroundColors = [UIColor.redColor(), UIColor.yellowColor(), UIColor.cyanColor()]
    }

    // MARK: UITableViewDataSource

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 100
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

        // do whatever cell configuration you want here

        // but programmatically set the background color (or whatever) based upon the model:

        if indexPath.row < 3 {
            cell.backgroundColor = cellBackgroundColors[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            cell.backgroundColor = defaultColor
        }

        return cell
    }

    // MARK: UITableViewDelegate

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)

        cellBackgroundColors[indexPath.row] = UIColor.blueColor()

        tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)

        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(3, target: self, selector: "resetCells:", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }

    // MARK: Timer code

    weak var timer: NSTimer?

    func resetCells(timer: NSTimer) {
        resetCellBackgroundColorsToDefault()

        let indexPaths = [0, 1, 2].map { NSIndexPath(forRow: $0, inSection: 0) }

        tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths, withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    }

}
```

Comment: The cells change colour and icon based on where you touch them. The more to the right you go the higher the result. Would I keep that calculation in the custom cell classes?

Comment: You have to update the model. You can either set up some delegate-protocol for the cell to inform the view controller so that it can update the model accordingly, or hook up the tap gesture/outlet directly to the view controller. You can have the cell update its color directly (and forgo the `updateCellsAtIndexPaths` that I did in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`), but you still want to update the model in case the cell scrolls of and then back on, triggering `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to be called again.

Comment: Thanks will have a go tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the problem is that you're creating new instances of Objects instead of using the ones on the screen.

Take for example,

`ResetTables().resetAllTables()`

which calls

```
func resetAllTables(){
  StressTableViewCell().resetStress()
  BmTableViewCell().resetBM()
  PainTableViewCell().resetPain()
}
```

What you're doing with `ResetTables()` is creating a new object of the class `ResetTables`, and then calling `resetAllTables()` on it, which in turn creates a new cell, `StressTableViewCell`, and calls `resetStress` on it. The same goes for the other two cells. Although you *are* calling the methods, you are not calling them on the displayed cells, but on new cells which, after the function leaves scope, get deallocated.

So in your `reset()` method, you want to reset the cell itself, and not create new cells that you reset.

Comment: Yes that is what I thought from the error messages I get.